# The Excel coordinates of the second monitor do not match

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I want to capture Excel on the second monitor. Win32gui.I used GetwindRect, but the coordinates don't seem to be accurate.

[image]

**second monitor image**

```py
import time
import win32gui
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

def shot(hwnd):
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    saveas='screenshot.png'
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1,y1,x2,y2))
    img.save(saveas)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        classname = win32gui.GetClassName(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
        print(classname)
        if classname == 'XLMAIN':
            hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(classname, None)
            if hwnd:
                shot(hwnd)
            break
```

Comment: What values do you expect? What values do you observe?

Answer (score 0):

To get the window coordinates on the second monitor, you need to handle the coordinates.

> [To position an object on a multiple monitor system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/positioning-objects-on-multiple-display-monitors)
>
> 1. Determine the appropriate monitor.
> 2. Get the coordinates to the monitor.
> 3. Position the object using the coordinates.
>
> To get the coordinates for the monitor, use [GetMonitorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmonitorinfoa), which
> provides both the work area and the entire monitor rectangle.
>
> [rcMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-monitorinfo#members): A RECT structure that specifies the display monitor
> rectangle, expressed in virtual-screen coordinates. Note that if the
> monitor is not the primary display monitor, some of the rectangle's
> coordinates may be negative values.

In other words, use `GetMonitorInfo` to obtain the virtual screen coordinates of the second monitor, and then add and subtract the excel coordinates obtained by `GetWindowRect`.

Code sample for reference(C++): [Positioning Objects on a Multiple Display Setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/positioning-objects-on-a-multiple-display-setup)

Comment: Hi,@SeungKyu Yu did this answer work for you? Please feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it if it did help to you.